# Make mapbox annotations draggable as soon as they are added to the map

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I have successfully managed to implement draggable annotations by using this link https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/draggable-views/. However, these annotations become draggable only after long pressing on them. I am looking for a solution wherein the annotations become draggable as soon as they are added to the map. Thanks a lot for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up coming up with my own implementation to suit my needs. Heres how I went about it:-

- Add the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on the annotation view of the annotation that needs to be dragged.
- In the gesture recognizer, convert the in-screen gesture location to real-world coordinates using the `mapView.convert(point, mapView)` method. Use these coordinates to update the location of the dragged coordinate
- Use the started and the ended state property of the gesture recognizer to determine the start and end of the drag gesture.